# word counter with regex in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, cpu-word, word-count

```
var words = "word worddd woord wooord 45555";

var wordCount = words.match(/([a-zA-Z]\w+)/g).length;

if(wordCount == 4 || wordCount == 6 ){
  WScript.Echo(wordCount);//Result 4
}
```

**How to make a ps1 script that work like like jscript**

Comment: Can we see your attempt at doing the conversion? I'm not familiar with jscript, but even I can translate that fairly easily. I'd recommend removing the Powershell version tags and only leaving the one that applies to your environment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a script writing service. 
We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far 
(including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck 
so that we can help with specific problems. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Maybe [about_Regular_Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking: the **[`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) cmdlet has a `-Word` switch**:

```sh
$words = "word worddd woord wooord"

$wordCount = ($words | Measure-Object -Word).Words

if ($wordCount -in 4, 6){
   $wordCount # -> 4
}
```

<sup>Note: If you really need PS **v2** support, use `4, 6 -contains $wordCount` in lieu of `$wordCount -in 4, 6`</sup>

---

**To restrict what is considered a word to something that starts with an (ASCII-range) *letter*,** as in your question, more work is needed:

```sh
$words = "word worddd woord wooord 45555"

# Count only words that start with an (ASCII-range) letter.
$wordCount = ((-split $words) -match '^[a-z]\w+$').Count

if ($wordCount -in 4, 6){
   $wordCount # -> 4, because '45555' wasn't counted.
}
```

- The unary form of `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), splits the string into an array of tokens by whitespace.
- `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), matches each resulting token agains the RHS regex:

  - `-match` finds *substrings* by default, hence the need for anchors `^` and `$`
  - `-match` is case-*insensitive* by default (as PowerShell generally is), so `[a-z]` covers both lower- and uppercase letters.
- `(...).Count` returns the length (element count) of the resulting array of matching tokens.